# Why is ISO date conversion not consistent in javascript environments and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

Locally, on Node 10.15.13, `new Date('01.01.2017')` results in *"2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"*.

Yet in the **browser**, or in the **docker image** (same node version) I build, it results in *"Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"*.

What is causing this discrepancy and how do you fix it in e.g. unit tests?

Comment: What are you using to show these values? some implementations could be calling toString() to pretty print the object.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: `$ docker run -ti node:10 node -`
`> new Date('01.01.2017');`
`2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` (from https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)

Comment: Ah no sorry I can :)

Comment: `'01.01.2017'` is not an ISO date.   Use `2017-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, your discrepancy is coming from the fact that your local machine (or server) have a timezone set, when your docker container does not.

Here is the first test I ran:

```bash
$ docker run -ti node:10 node -
> new Date('01.01.2017');
2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Then I wondered about the possibility that the timezone of the server could have an influence on the answer, and indeed it did:

```bash
$ docker run -ti node:10 env TZ=Europe/Brussels node  -
> new Date('01.01.2017');
2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
```

You can correlate that with those two *system* date results:

- Without any timezone set

  ```bash
  $ docker run -ti node:10 date
  Mon Mar 18 22:17:43 UTC 2019
  ```
- With a timezone set

  ```bash
  $ docker run -ti node:10 env TZ=Europe/Brussels date
  Mon Mar 18 23:17:59 CET 2019
  ```

---

Since you pointed at the exact version you tried to use, I still have a reproductible behavior, from my side:

- Without timezone set

  ```bash
  $ docker run -ti node:10.15.3 node -
  > new Date('01.01.2017');
  2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
  ```

- With timezone set

  ```bash
  $ docker run -ti node:10.15.3 env TZ=Europe/Brussels node  -
  > new Date('01.01.2017');
  2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured the issue out. I did set timezone, but it wasn't accepted by the base image. It's the node:10.15.13. I ended up going with node:10.10 which is working perfectly. I will later comment it in the docker forum if I have the time.

Comment: @TheGabornator still unsure on why you cannot reproduce. I definitely can reproduce the exact same behavior on that specific version: see the updated answer

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cannot reproduce" I didn't have this issue locally, only on 10.15.13, only in the docker container. Locally, it didn't have to be reproduced, and in the container I couldn't solve it, so I just used an older version of the base image.

Comment: @TheGabornator 1/ No such version of node as 10.15.13. The latest is 10.15.3 LTS. Are you sure of your version number? 2/ Locally, you have not the same behavior as on the docker container because your local machine is most likely timezoned to `Europe/Berlin` (based on your profile), so that makes sense that you end up with a UTC-1 hour. When a server booted without any timezone set would be on UTC timezone and will 'behaves' as you expected given the fact your date is not an ISO one (see [@Alnitak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55231121/2123530))

Answer (score 2):

The string `"01.01.2017"` is *not* an ISO date string, and will be parsed ambiguously depending both on your time zone, and your locale (i.e. whether you use day/month or month/day).

To get unambiguous parsing of a date, use proper ISO 8601 format, e.g.

```
2017-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

where the `Z` indicates that the timestamp is in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue out. I did set timezone, but it wasn't accepted by the base image. It's the node:10.15.13. I ended up going with node:10.10 which is working perfectly. I will later comment it in the docker forum if I have the time.

Comment: I guess you meant node 10.15.3, then?